# Update nested attributes before saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

Long time reader of Stackoverflow but have never found myself in a position to ask a question (that hasn't already been answered).  I guess there's a first time for everything so here it goes...

**System Info:** 
Ruby Version = 1.8.7 
Rails Version = 3.2.2

**Situation:**
We have an application with a user registration system in place.  In order to hook up and populate all of our tables correctly, we are utilizing Complex/Nested Forms within the registration view.  I actually have the nested forms working perfectly, everything is being populated as it should, its awesome really.

Here is the problem:  I need to set one of the value of one of the nested attributes AFTER the form post but BEFORE the records are saved.

Here is a quick example so you can see what I'm talking about a little bit better:
A user registers with our site.  When they register a record is created in the Users data table.  Each user is also classified as a team_mate (join table) and assigned to their very own individual team (at first).  But, a 'team' (table) also has an 'alias' field in it which, on the initial creation of the user we would like to set to the users first name (without having to have them enter their first name into an 'alias' field on the form).

**So, I guess the question would be:**  How to I manually set the value of a nested attribute after the form post and before the records are saved to the database?

A (simplistic) example of the table schema looks is as follows:

Users (id, first_name, last_name, created_at, updated_at)

Team_mates(id, user_id, team_id, created_at, updated_at) - join table

Teams(id, alias, created_at, updated_at)

**Models:**

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_mates, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :teams, :through => :team_mates, :foreign_key => :team_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team_mates, :allow_destroy => true

  before_save :set_defaults

  private
    def set_defaults
      #want to set :users => :team_mates_attributes => :team_attributes => :alias to @user.first_name here

      # Would prefer to handle this here instead of in the controller.
    end
  end
```

Team.rb

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_mates, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :team_mates, :foreign_key => :user_id

end
```

Team_mate.rb

```
class TeamMate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**Controller**

Users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.emails.build(:is_default_email => 1)
  @user.build_login

  @user.team_mates.build.build_team(:alias => 'Clinton444', :created_at => Time.new, :updated_at => Time.new)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @match }
  end
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  @user.attributes = ({ "user" => { "team_mates" => { "team" => { "alias" => @user.first_name } } } }) #--this doesn't work...

  @user.attributes = ({ :user => { :team_mates => { :team => { :alias => @user.first_name } } } }) #--neither does this...


  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html  { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
      format.json  { render :json => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
    else
      format.html  { render :action => "new" }
      format.json  { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**View**

new.html.haml

```
  = form_for(@user, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
- if @user.errors.any?
  .alert
    %h2
      = pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")
      prohibited this post from being saved:
    %ul
      - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li
          = msg
%fieldset
.control-group
  = f.label :first_name, :class => "control-label"
  .controls
    =f.text_field :first_name, :class => "span8"

.control-group
  = f.label :last_name, :class => "control-label"
  .controls
    =f.text_field :last_name, :class => "span8"

= f.fields_for :emails do |e|
  =e.hidden_field :is_default_email, :class => "span8"

  .control-group
    = e.label :email, :class => "control-label"
    .controls
      =e.text_field :email, :class => "span8"

= f.fields_for :team_mates do |tm|
  = tm.fields_for :team do |t|
    =t.hidden_field :alias, :class => "span8"
    =t.hidden_field :created_at, :class => "span8"
    =t.hidden_field :updated_at, :class => "span8"

= f.fields_for :login do |e|
  .control-group
    = e.label :user_login, :class => "control-label"
    .controls
      =e.text_field :user_login, :class => "span8"

  .control-group
    = e.label :password_encrypted, :class => "control-label"
    .controls
      =e.text_field :password_encrypted, :class => "span8"

.control-group
  .controls
    =f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-medium'
```

**And finally**

Rails server output on form post

```
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"team_mates_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"team_attributes"=>{"created_at"=>"Wed Jun 06 09:52:19 -0600 2012", "alias"=>"asfs444", "updated_at"=>"Wed Jun 06 09:52:19 -0600 2012"}}}, "first_name"=>"lkjlkjlsdfslkjeowir", "last_name"=>"ouisodifuoixv", "emails_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"is_default_email"=>"1", "email"=>"lpisfsopf@psflsjdk.com"}}, "login_attributes"=>{"user_login"=>"lkjsdfooiusfd", "password_encrypted"=>"[FILTERED]"}}, "utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Create User", "authenticity_token"=>"CQLQ93/0VlncSzMlmtLPHgaVrrvjuHFN+lN6CYCsiR8="}
```

After looking at the models you might be wondering where emails/logins are coming from.  They're built within the model on our system, but are not really part of this question so I omitted the code for them.  They are working, so the problem isn't on that side.

Comment: did you manage to solve this one? I too want to massage the attributes after submission (preferably) but before saving.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes

> To support both the creation of new objects and the editing of
>   existing ones we have to use an array of hashes for one-to-many
>   associations or a single hash for one-to-one associations. If no :id
>   property exists then it is assumed to represent a nested model to
>   create.

Not 100% sure.. I haven't used\tested it before, but this should give you an idea

```
@user.teams.each do |team| 
  team.team_mates do |team_mate|
    # To edit existing
    team_mate.team_attributes = [ { :id => team.id,  :alias => @user.first_name } ]

    # To create new
    team_mate.team_attributes = [ { :alias => @user.first_name } ]

    team_mate.save
  end 
end
```

Comment: I can see where you are going with the code snippet above. I modified it slightly (in a few different ways).  I can get it to execute without errors, but alias never ends up being updated. I think the above example is close, but not quite there.

Comment: Maybe you need to save it? (team_mate.save)

Comment: @user.save is actually being called right after the code executes, so that's already in there.  Out of abundance of caution, I tried it with team.save and it still didn't work. ( I know you said 'team_mate.save but the code I am testing is slightly different than what you suggested - same concept, but I go into team_mates first since team is a nested attribute of team_mates)